# Interpreting Serial Port Data

Tags: serial-port

I have a speed radar system that has a com port on the back.  I've connected to it by a USB serial adapter.  The com port can be used to connect an external display, or connect to a video system.  I'm using RealTerm to connect to it.  The information being displayed doesn't appear to make any sense.  The information being displayed does change if the radar system detects changes in speed.

This is basically what I see on the screen:

No speed:

```
À    À    À    À
```

Changes in speed:

```
 Ä  Ä  Ä  Ä  Ä
```

My end goal is to pipe the data into our CCTV system.

Can someone point me in the right direction to start with?

Comment: The serial com will send you data in the form of bytes. to make sense out of it, first you need to make sure you have correct serial port settings such as baud rate. it is vital to set it up correct so that you know you are receiving the correct bytes. Second read the group of bytes convert them to something you know. This will all be fully explained on your serial device manual.

Comment: If you need further help let me know.

Comment: There's no manual for it.  I bought the device second hand.  The data does change depending on baud rate, but I don't know what the correct rate should be at this point.

Comment: *"I don't know what the correct rate should be"* -- The baud rate can be measured with an oscilloscope.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you bought the device second hand, you can find the manual online. What is the name of the device?

Comment: It's a Python III made my MPH Industries.  Exact model is PYTHONK 880846. [This](http://www.njdiscoverydocs.com/images/stories/documents/S/Stratford%20Borough/Python%20Series%20II%20Radar%20Operator's%20Manual%20-%20September%2026,%202013.pdf) is the closest I could come up with in terms of a manual.  It's for an older model.  It briefly covers the serial port on page 16.  [Link](http://www.mphindustries.com/python-iii/) to manufacturer page.

Comment: @Go3Team I didn't realise you posted a comment above, I didn't get the notification. I will have a look at the data sheet and come back to you.

Comment: @Go3Team I couldn't find any instruction regarding the serial port connection either. I would suggest get some reading (ideally in hex display) from the lowest baud rate onwards. it is going to be little difficult to reverse engineer the comms protocol.

Comment: I've emailed the manufacturer to see if they'll provide it.  I do appreciate your help.